# SQL How to query for earliest stock price?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has rows for various stock prices at various times of the day for many different companies.  Each row is a stocks price at a particular time of day. The times are not the same for each stock.

I can't figure out how to query for the price of each stock at the earliest time point.

For example, from the below example table I would want the query to return:
ABC 1.25
XYZ 0.95

*[Stock]*      *[Trade Time]*    *[Price]*

ABC            9:35            1.25

ABC       9:55          1.15

ABC      10:35          1.50

XYZ       9:47          0.95

XYZ       9:53          1.00

XYZ      11:10          0.85

Comment: topicstarter you will have to replace `MAX()` with `MIN()` if you follow @Nick 's suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

A simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.tradetime = (select min(t2.tradetime) from t t2 where t2.stock = t.stock);
```